# I need a mysql query will it will return the NUMBER of rows matched, not an array with the rows matched

Tags: php, mysql

Basically im doing a login script where the username must be checked in the database before user gets logged in.  So I need a mysql query that will return ONLY the number of records matched from the target table with the specified username, AND NOT an array with the records.  I tried this:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT COUNT(*) from usersecurity WHERE Email ='$username'" );
```

but apparrently it returns a result resource and not a int or number value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT COUNT(*) from usersecurity WHERE Email ='$username'" );
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
print($row[0]) //0 or 1, etc
```

Answer (score 2):

use [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) on the returned resource

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * from usersecurity WHERE Email ='$username'" );
$count = mysql_num_rows( $result );
```

Comment: @colinmarc: Galen's provided example does not use COUNT()

Comment: It did before he changed it. I deleted my comment and undid my downvote =)

Comment: it's ok , but very slow if that table is large, so the method provided by colinmarc is  better

Answer (score 1):

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

"For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error."

In other words mysql_query will ALWAYS return a resource.

what you can use for quick validation is

```
mysql_num_of_rows($result) > 0
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

or `if(!empty(mysql_fetch_row($result))`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you still need this to retrieve your results

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result)
```

$row[0] will be your integer.